# How to stop nant exec task putting ( ) around command line

Tags: nant, exec

I have looked through the nant documentation and sourceforge faq and can't find the answer to this question.  The exec task in nant puts ( ) around the command line parameters it generates, so for example this task below would generate:

mallow ( -1 )

```
    <exec program="${build.tools.wix}\mallow.exe"
  workingdir="${build.out.xxx}">
      <arg value="-1" />
    </exec>
```

The other open source tool I'm using - mallow - cannot handle this.

Does anyone know of a way to stop nant putting the ( ) around the arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of NAnt are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) does not actually put parentheses around the arguments, it just looks like that when you use `verbose` as in

```
<target name="test">
    <exec program="echo" verbose="True">
        <arg value="-1" />
        <arg value="0" />
        <arg value="1" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

from which the output is `-1 0 1`, and not `(-1 0 1)` as it would be if you ran

```
echo (-1 0 1)
```

directly from the command line.